# Reload a whole page after clicking a follow button on visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, refresh

Can anyone tell me how to reload or refresh a whole page after clicking a follow button on Visualforce Page?
My VFP as follows;

```
 <script>
       funtion reload(){
           window.location.reload( true );
       }
   </script>

   <apex:repeat value="{!userList}" var="user">
      <apex:outputText value="{!user.Name}" /><chatter:follow entityId="{!user.id}" onComplete="reload();"/>


   </apex:repeat>
```

But the above code doesnt perform very well!
So What Ive to modify in that page?

Thanks in advance
Karthick

Answer (score 1):

The code below should work

```
<apex:repeat value="{!userList}" var="user">
  <apex:outputText value="{!user.Name}" /><chatter:follow entityId="{!user.id}" onComplete="window.location.reload();"/></apex:repeat>
```

Thanks
Saranya

Comment: No that s y am asking

Comment: I tried and it worked for me. I used this code by replacing the list to accounts

Comment: This is the code I used                                                               <apex:page standardController="Account">
<apex:form>
   <apex:repeat value="{!Account.Contacts}" var="user">
      <apex:outputText value="{!user.Name}" /><chatter:follow entityId="{!user.id}" onComplete="window.location.reload();"/>
</apex:repeat>
</apex:form> </apex:page>

Comment: Oh ..Can you share your code to my mail id(pskarthick.sonacse23@gmail.com)